# Get true value of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Recently I encountered an issue with the `textarea`. If I have a textarea likeso,

```
<textarea>Hello World</textarea>
```

And I get the contents of it with JS,

```
var textareaText = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value
```

The variable `textareaText` is `Hello World`. But if I were to change the value of the `textarea` and re-run the JS. It would still result in `Hello World` despite the true current value being something else. I've looked this up and seen +5 answers but all of them use jQuery which is something I don't use or know (to translate) and none pure JS. If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated. Also some of the answers seemed to be just for one textarea. In my project I'd have +1,000 so I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902971/html-input-not-updating-value), HTML doesn't automatically update an input or textarea's value when changed. Check the link to see how you can use JS to watch the textarea and update the value of a variable assigned whenever it is changed.

Comment: @AndrewL Thanks, any idea what the jQuery would be in pure JS?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: 1000 textareas on a single page? How does anyone navigate that kind of form?

Comment: Actually it may be more like 200, I was was counting people, not families (which it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, no matter how many `<textarea>`'s you use, this should work:

```
<textarea id="textarea1">hello</textarea>
<textarea id="textarea2">goodbye</textarea>
<button id="button">button</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = function() {
        alert(document.getElementById("textarea1").value + "\n" + document.getElementById("textarea2").value);
    };
</script>
```

I just tested it and it works, no matter which values I change, and even if I change both. The trick is to **not** store the values, as they aren't updated, so you should get the value on-the-spot.

Although it was against the questions guidelines, with "1000+" textareas, setting a JavaScript variable for each one might slow down loading times. May I suggest jQuery, with the same HTML?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").on("click", function () {
        alert($("#textarea1").val() + "\n" + $("#textarea2").val());
    });
</script>
```

Of course, feel free to mix up and change up the code provided above. Hope this helps!

Comment: So the trick is to set a variable for each textarea so JS can keep track of it?

Comment: @JackStoller After I changed it, it didn't work, so I changed it back to the repetitive answer just now

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in my computer:

```js
function getText(){
  var textareaText = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
  console.log(textareaText);
};
```

```html
  <textarea>Hello World</textarea><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="getText();">Get text</button>
```

Comment: Same, but not in my program, weird.

Answer (score -1):

May be?

```
<textarea id="text-area">Hello World</textarea>
```

```js
    var el = document.getElementById("text-area");
    var textareaText;
    el.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    textareaText = e.target.value;
        console.log(e.target.value);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue still continues. I don't think the issue is how I am selecting the textarea, but rather its functionalities.

Comment: You might have to add input event listener to update the value if that is what you want.